# Facebook app iFrame auto height generating an scrollbar

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, iframe, facebook-canvas

I'm creating an Facebook app inside an page. Issue is I'm getting scroll bar in all the browsers.

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId: '$App.Id',
        xfbml: false, // no social plugins
        version: '$App.Version'
      });
      FB.Canvas.setSize({width:810, height:1162});

      FB.Canvas.getPageInfo(function(response) {
        fbAppHelper.platform = 'tab';
      });
    };
```

I found a code to get rid off this issue, which not work for me:

```
$(document).on( "pagecontainertransition", function( event, ui ) {
   FB.Canvas.setSize({height:600});
   setTimeout("FB.Canvas.setAutoGrow()",500);
});
```

My html/css:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="page">my content</div>
</div>

.wrapper {
    width: 810px;
    max-width: 100%;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: It might be because your `.wrappers` height is being scaled to be smaller than the height of what your setting on the Facebook canvas. What happens when you change the height of the wrapper from `height: auto` to `height: 1162px`?

Comment: if I do that, It'll create an white space in the bottom of other pages